# What is the significance of the name at the end of this 1843 advertisement?

Tags: 19th-century, new-york-state, 1840s

The following advertisement appeared in [The New York State Register (1843)](https://books.google.com/books?id=2PQCAAAAYAAJ&dq=col.%20lyman%20j.%20strong&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

[image]

What is the meaning of the name at the bottom of the page, "Col. Lyman J. Strong, New-Orleans", in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that George White's New York firm is looking to make collateralized loans. Harden & Co. and Lyman J. Strong are working as agents and mortgage brokers in various cities, verifying deeds and assets to approve borrowers.

It is common today, but first became really practical after the invention of the telegraph. Your early ad dated 1843 is the same year Samuel Morse began building his cable service emanating from New York and reaching Washington, Buffalo, Boston and New Orleans. George White probably relied more on the post office for the first couple years.

As the telegraph expanded to more cites, brokers and bankers from New York began seeking satellite offices, clients, and investors from across the country. It was somewhat rare before the Civil War, but after the Trans-Atlantic Cable was finished around 1866, and financial news and stock ticker service began around 1870, there was a boom that continued through the turn of the century. Major financial papers were littered with similar ads.

Comment: Have you seen similar cases in your own research, or have any links to finding aids for records or reference guides? If so, please add them to your answer.

Comment: Yes, I have seen dozens of these. Not in genealogical pursuits, but in the study of 19th century financial news services.